# nested ng-repeat always shows the last item in the array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a requirement of showing a list of Categories and Subcategories in two tables. For showing the Category data, in HTML :

```
 <tr ng-repeat="item in addNodeCtrl.categoryData track by $index">
 <td>{{item.name}}</td>
 <td>
 <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.active">
```

Here it will show the Category and Category active/Inactive switch in the first table.

In the second table, I need to show only the categories in the first table that have been made active through the switch. It will show the subcategories and its active/inactive status. HTML below:

```
  <table ng-repeat="item in ctrl.categoryData | filter:{active:true} track by $index" ng-init="ctrl.getsubCategory(item.id)">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>{{item.name}}></td>
            <td>
                <table>
                <tr ng-repeat="item1 in ctrl.subCategoryData track by $index">
                     <td>{{item1.name}}</td>     
         <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="item1.active">    
                     </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
           </td>
           </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
```

item.id is the category ID and the getsubCategory function in JS is given below

JS Below:

```
function getsubCategory(categoryid) {

  getsubcategservice.getsubcateg({categoryid: categoryid},{})
            .$promise.then(success,failure);

            function success(response){
                    vm.subCategoryData = response.data.subCategorys; 
                }

                               function failure(reason){
                            //error message
                }


}
```

The issue here is that when i make the first category switch active , the subcategories are populated, but when the second category switch is made active, the first set of subcategories also changes and lists the subcategories for the second category that was made active.

Please find the JSON data for Category below:

```
    {
  "categoryInfoes": {
    "categoryInfo": [
      {
        "active": "true",
        "description": "category 1",
        "id": "1",

      },

      {
        "active": "true",
        "description": "category 2",
        "id": "2",
      },
      {
        "active": "true",
        "description": "category 3",
        "id": "3",
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Please find the JSON for subcategory below:

```
{
  "subcategoryDetails": {
    "subCategorys": [
      {
        "active": "true",
        "name": "1 - subcategory 1",
      },
      {
        "active": "true",
        "name": "1 - subcategory 2",
      },
      {
        "active": "true",
        "name": "1 - subcategory 3",
      },
      {
        "active": "true",
        "name": "1 - subcategory 4",
      }
    ],
    "active": "true",
    "description": "category 1",
    "id": "1",   
  }
}

{
  "subcategoryDetails": {
    "subCategorys": [
      {
        "active": "true",
        "name": "2 - subcategory 1",
      },
      {
        "active": "true",
        "name": "2 - subcategory 2",
      },
      {
        "active": "true",
        "name": "2 - subcategory 3",
      },

    ],
    "active": "true",
    "description": "category 2",
    "id": "2",   
  }
}

{
  "subcategoryDetails": {
    "subCategorys": [
      {
        "active": "true",
        "name": "3 - subcategory 1",
      },
      {
        "active": "true",
        "name": "3 - subcategory 2",
      },
      {
        "active": "true",
        "name": "3 - subcategory 3",
      },

    ],
    "active": "true",
    "description": "category 3",
    "id": "3",   
  }
}
```

Could anyone help me out on this?

**UPDATE:**

I have created a Plunker to demonstrate this:
https://plnkr.co/edit/LqioF8hugsjJCOfmj9Vb?p=preview

If you see in the Plunk, If you check "Category 2" after checking "Category 1", the subcategories get updated for both Category 1 and 2. Same happpens for Category 3. The Subcategory for the last item is updated everywhere.
Please help me out on this and let me know what I am doing wrong,

Comment: Not clear how `<switch>` works

Comment: You can ignore the switch. I had added an angular Switch library for that. I have edited the code to <input checkbox>

Comment: Suggest you create a demo in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) for this. Hard to help without seeing UI and inspecting in dev tools

Comment: @charlietfl, I have created a Plunker to demonstrate this. Link in the Original Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are loading the subcategories into scope, and then changing the value in scope each time a category is selected.  As far as Angular is concerned, you just wanted to repeat and display that information multiple times.  One way to solve this would be to nest the subcategories into their parent category object and bind the ng-repeat to the child sub-categories of their parent.

You can even still load these on the fly when they are selected, if the amount of data is prohibitive to load everything at once.

Let me know if that makes sense.

**-- Edit --**
Since I haven't heard from you in a day, I decided to add a plunkr to show you what I was talking about:

https://plnkr.co/edit/mquYiX?p=preview

Here is the controller:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$http) {

  // I made the subcategory data an array
  $scope.subcategoryData = [];

    $http.get("data.json")
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.categoryData = response.data;
    });


$scope.getsubCategory = function (categoryid) {
  $http.get("data"+categoryid+".json")
      .then(function(response) {
        // the subcategories are keyed on the category Id
        // and updated each time the method is called
        $scope.subcategoryData[categoryid] = response.data;
        console.log($scope.subcategoryData[categoryid]);
      })
    };  

});
```

And here is your html:

```
<table ng-repeat="item in categoryData.categorydetail | filter:{active:true} track by $index" >
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>{{item.name}}></td>
        <td ng-init="getsubCategory(item.id)">
          <table>
            <!-- here, I key the subcategoryData in the loop on the Item id.  Voila, now it works -->
            <tr ng-repeat="item1 in subcategoryData[item.id].subcategoryinfo track by $index">
             <td>{{item1.subname}}</td>     
             <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="item1.subactive"></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: Maurice, I have deleted the query above. Please see the new Plunker link in original Question which demonstrates the problem I am facing.

Comment: I got your point of nesting the subcategory in parent category Object, but the backend in my Project is a seperate Team and the data  model is designed like this and is used in other places as well. So I am not sure changing this is feasible. Please let me know if there is  a solution with the current data model. Thanks for the suggestion anyway,

Comment: It's absolutely feasible.  Have an array in each category object that is initially set to null.  When the user selects a category, you run a method in your controller which checks that sub category array.  If the array is null, then it fires off a call to your webservice to get the subcategories for selected category.  If there's none, return an empty array.  If there are subcategories then you return the ones you need.  Then you bind the second ng-repeat to the subcategories array that's part of your item.

Comment: Or you create an array in the controller, that is keyed to the parent category Id, and then you bind the second ng-repeat to that array, based on the category ID.

Comment: @VijayMenon - I've updated my answer above with a working plunkr and code examples.  Please review, and if you this fixes your problem, please mark my answer as the accepted one.  Thanks!

Comment: Maurice, Sorry for the late reply. Your solution is what I was looking for!! Thanks for the detailed explanation and the Plunker.